# Reverse Scrolling synaptics touchpad

Tags: windows, drivers, touchpad

I am using synaptics touch pad driver for my laptop. I want to disable reverse scrolling. How can I do it using this driver? There is no  reverse scrolling option.

Screen Shot: http://postimg.org/image/ck4qhd6w1/

OS: Windows 8 (Lenovo G580)

Comment: What's “Chiral Scrolling”, and have you tried toggling it?

Comment: @blacklight I tried before ,but didn't Work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's up to the driver coder. If there is no option to disable reverse scrolling already there, you probably can't do it without a registry tweak or something.

Comment: any other Driver that support my touchpad ....

Comment: You might be able to get more features if you update your driver. http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/default.page?selector=expand